# Jasmine Array Compare Partial Object Test

Tags: angular, jasmine

Is there a `jasmine` specific way of checking if an array matches another array, with partial object comparison?

The arrays may be large (pulled from test data files) - so was trying to avoid adding in comparisons of each array item individually

```js
const originalArray = [
  { a: 0, b: 0, random: 0},
  { a: 1, b: 1, random: 0},
  ...
]

const testArray = [
  { a: 0, b: 0},
  { a: 1, b: 1},
  ...
]

// I know this isn't right
expect(originalArray).toEqual(testArray);
```

Maybe there's some combination of Array test with `toEqual` and `jasmine.objectContaining`?

Answer (score 1):

> The arrays may be large (pulled from test data files) - so was trying to avoid adding in comparisons of each array item individually

`toEqual` most likely compares each element in the array, it is just not shown explicitly.

You can possibly do a `forEach`, something like this:

```
originalArray.forEach((item, index) => {
  expect(item).toContain(jasmine.objectContaining(testArray[index]));
});
```